# IPv6 + PTR + gmail returning error

Tags: centos, domain, ipv6, exim

I have a problem with mail connected to gmail account. Every time when i wanna send mail i got that error:

> Our system has detected that this message does not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and authentication

From server providoer i got IPv6 addreses: 2001:41D0:2:DFb7::/64

I add records to file piorkowski.pl.db:

```
piorkowski.pl.   IN   AAAA   2001:41D0:2:DFb7::1
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7.b.f.d.2.0.0.0.0.d.1.4.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. IN PTR piorkowski.pl.
```

And on server provider i add reverse for IPv6.

Command

```
dig AAAA piorkowski.pl +nocomments
```

return valid ip addres

the entire contents of piorkowski.pl.db:

```
$TTL 14400
@       IN      SOA     ns318558.ovh.net.      hostmaster.piorkowski.pl. (
                                                2014072700
                                               14400
                                                3600
                                                1209600
                                                86400 )

piorkowski.pl.   14400   IN   NS   ns318558.ovh.net.
piorkowski.pl.   14400   IN   NS   sdns2.ovh.net.

*.piorkowski.pl.   14400   IN   A   188.165.23.11
ftp   14400   IN   A   188.165.23.11
localhost   14400   IN   A   127.0.0.1
mail   14400   IN   A   188.165.23.11
piorkowski.pl.   14400   IN   A   188.165.23.11
pop   14400   IN   A   188.165.23.11
smtp   14400   IN   A   188.165.23.11
www   14400   IN   A   188.165.23.11
piorkowski.pl.   14400   IN   AAAA   2001:41D0:2:DFb7::1
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7.b.f.d.2.0.0.0.0.d.1.4.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa. IN     PTR piorkowski.pl.
piorkowski.pl.   14400   IN   MX   10 mail



piorkowski.pl.   14400   IN   TXT   "v=spf1 a mx ip4:188.165.23.11 ~all"

localhost   14400   IN   AAAA   ::1
```

How stop quotes?

Comment: Your host `mail` does not have an IPv6 address set. This might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I change for IPv6 but that don give any result.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put `PTR` in the same file as `A` or `AAAA`.

It may seem that because you provided a fully qualified record, the bind would find it. But it won't; bind has no "map" of what to look in which file. It looks at a query from the client, then it looks in named.conf and based solely on named.conf entries it already knows how to serve the request: from which zone file (or forwarders, or recursive searching). If the query contain suffix `piorkowski.pl` it knows, based on named.conf, that it should respond with something it reads off `piorkowski.pl.db` file.

Similarly, you need to point in named.conf to the `arpa` domain that contains the PTR records. And ISP should obviously delegate the domain to your NS; there is no special PTR-type domain, domain is a domain and is normally delegated, whether it contains A records or PTR records.